# My HTML page does not upload at the top of the page

Tags: header, html

I am just in my first year of a computing degree. I am looking for a job, unfortunately I have to go back to accounts as nobody is keen to hire someone after just one year of computing studies, with almost zero experience. However, I thought to make it interesting and create an online Curriculum Vitae, as my job history is all over the place and it's a lot harder to keep in on a 2 page word doc.

What I have done so far, it's here: http://lavinia.gear.host/

Just a simple site, using Bootstrap (as I was curious to try it), minimal JS, HTML and CCS.

As you notice, when you go on the website, it does not show the top part, the actual site menu, how normally any site uploads or refreshes. It starts almost at the bottom of the page, where the contact form is. I did remove the contact form but it's the same thing, the webpage defaults to the same area. I really have no idea why and how can I solve it? Maybe it's something to do with Bootstrap, some hidden thing I am not aware of?

If you want the actual code, I will supply it but since it's quite a lot for a small page, I thought maybe you can just view the code source directly.

Any advice is much appreciated. I cannot send a E Resume when it's always getting to that contact form, it's annoying, even if accounts people will look at it.

Thank you,
Lavinia

Answer (score 1):

That's because your input element is set to autofocus:

```
<input type="text" size="50" name="VisitorName" maxlength="30" required="" autofocus="">
```

Remove the autofocus attribute and it should be fine:

```
<input type="text" size="50" name="VisitorName" maxlength="30" required="">
```

Comment: he said he had the same problem even without  the form

Comment: @TilakMadichetti, Yes he said so, but I don't think normally page should do that. I think, he didn't check it well or there must be some other similar problem. There shouldn't be any need to use javascript to open that page normally at the top. That's the normal behaviour after all. Thanks for pointing out though :)

Comment: I know dude, but who would want to scroll and scrape every piece of code in the huge website - so i chose that hacky kind of a fix.

Comment: @TilakMadichetti so you're like me ;) a lazy hacky twisty JS developer.

Comment: Oh yeah Mike. Like you. By the way do you have any idea why people down voted my answer? Does or lack the quality?

Comment: @TilakMadichetti As per my understanding, simply because that's a quick hack and the problem doesn't need to be that complicated. In fact, I still think it can be done without that hack ;)